# REST API - How to get parameters from main route to nested one?

Tags: node.js, rest, nested-routes

I'm working on a rest api in which I'm using middlewares and trying to set nested routes.

i got something like this:

```
router.use('/route/:param/day, router1);
router.use('/route/:param/year, router2);


router1.get('/:day/:month/:year', function(req, res){
...
});
```

The parameter refers to the type of research that I have to do into my database and I need to know the kind and the date to do the proper request.
the thing is, I would like to get the param from the parent into the nested one, I set `mergeParams: true` but I cannot get it, it's always undefined.

Comment: `var router1 = express.Router({mergeParams: true});` is supposed to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check your express version. mergeParams available from express 4.5.0+. reference:http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: i am currently in 4.0.0 that's why mergin params did not work. Thanks!